# Cloud Storage crashes on launch with No Default Storage bucket found. Swift 4 Xcode 9

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-storage, cloud-storage

podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Tx' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Tx
   pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod ‘Firebase/Database’
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
  pod 'Firestore', :podspec => 'https://storage.googleapis.com/firebase-preview-drop/ios/firestore/0.7.0/Firestore.podspec.json'

end
```

AppDelegate:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import Firestore
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: "1tester1@gmail.com", password: "1tester1")
        { (user, error) in
            if let error = error
            {
                print ("Login failed \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }else{
                print ("Successful login")
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

View Controller:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import Firestore
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var ptImage: UIImageView!

    var db          : Firestore!         //Firestore
    let storage     = Storage.storage()
    var dbRef       : DatabaseReference! //FireBase

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        fetchPtPic()
    }//---------------

    func fetchPtPic()
    {
        let TxPtID = "JJ"
        db    = Firestore.firestore()
        dbRef = Database.database().reference()
        let storageRef    = storage.reference()
        let ptImagesRef   = storageRef.child("PtImages/\(TxPtID).jpg")
    }
```

It builds and crashes with a SIGABRT before executing anything.
If I comment out these lines:

```
//let storage     = Storage.storage()
//var dbRef       : DatabaseReference! //FireBase
```

and these:

```
//dbRef = Database.database().reference() //points to the whole /
//let storageRef    = storage.reference()
//let ptImagesRef   = storageRef.child("PtImages/\(TxPtID).jpg")
```

...then it compiles and executes clean.

Suggestions? I have been trying many things and other suggestions for 2 weeks and I am stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Firebase Storage rules allows you to read and write.

or

This is the root Firebase Storage Reference:

```
let storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference()
```

try the above line.

Comment: Swift 4 changes it to let storageRef  = storage.reference(). Still croaks.